# Entering menu only via Alt key

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem

I have to solve how to enter the Menu only by tapping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in my WPF app. The thing is, that I can get into the menu by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. And I don't want that. I would like to stay only in the "tab"/grid I am in. I have tried solving it by setting `Focusable` and `IsTabStop` properties. One way or another, it does not work. I can get into the menu but then I can't move on the next item or I cannot insert the menu at all.
Any ideas how to solve it? I hope there is simple and elegant solution which I am not seeing.

Comment: Plain Menu or in a ToolBarTray or something?

Comment: Could handle the key down event and mark enter has handled if you are not on the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dynamically alter the IsTabStop property.  This worked pretty well:

```
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        enableMenuTabs(false);
        menu1.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus += delegate { enableMenuTabs(true); };
        menu1.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += delegate { enableMenuTabs(false); };
    }

    private void enableMenuTabs(bool enable) {
        foreach (Control item in menu1.Items) item.IsTabStop = enable;
    }
```